# How can I debug TestCafe to see why it stopped reporting pass or fail midway through running tests?

Tags: testcafe

Overnight I have 250+ TestCafe tests running on a server usually without any problem, however last night results stopped being reported after the 90th test but the remaining tests continued to run.

When the tests are ran the console output is recorded into a file and from looking in this file I can see the result for each test like below.

`[ Γ£û ] My automated test`

However after the result for the 90th test is logged there are no more logs for the results of remaining tests. I know that the remaining tests have ran because in the test I'm seeing messages that are logged in the console when the various stages of a test are hit.

Does anyone have an idea what may have caused the tests to stop reporting their results or have any suggestions for how I may be able to debug this issue?

Comment: Try redirecting the TestCafe report to an external file as described [here](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/command-line-interface.html#-r-nameoutput---reporter-nameoutput). Then, collect TestCafe debug logs as follows:

`set DEBUG='testcafe*'
testcafe chrome e2e/**/* -r spec:report.log 2>testcafe_debug.log`

If that doesn't help and the issue appears regularly, please [submit](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md) a bug report with an example where it is reproduced.

Comment: I've experienced this issue before, when running tests concurrently. For me, 1 stream crashed (seems like your 90th test), while the other streams continued to run. TestCafe likely paused reporting, waiting on results from the run that crashed